# Objective-C Declaring object as a totally different class than what I declared

Tags: objective-c, ios, memory-leaks, automatic-ref-counting

In a method I wrote, I'm declaring an instance of class 'A' and calling a method on it. At run time, when the method runs, my app crashes. It says an unrecognized selector was sent to an instance of class 'B' even though I declared an instance of 'A'. I read somewhere that I may not be managing my memory correctly so it's sending the method to another class, but I'm using ARC so that shouldn't even be a problem. Help would be much appreciated!

```
The error I'm getting:
2011-08-27 01:25:49.859 Intelligenda[49385:bc03] PVC: <HomeViewController: 0x59359e0>
2011-08-27 01:25:49.945 Intelligenda[49385:bc03] -[HomeViewController addNewClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59359e0
2011-08-27 01:25:49.947 Intelligenda[49385:bc03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[HomeViewController addNewClass:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x59359e0'
```

and the method that's being called:

```
-(IBAction)done:(id)sender{

    [teacherName resignFirstResponder];
    [className resignFirstResponder];

    IntelligendaAppDelegate *delegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    UINavigationController *nav = delegate.navController;

    [nav popViewControllerAnimated:YES];

    ClassesViewController *classesParentViewController = (ClassesViewController *) nav.topViewController;

    ClassIG *theNewClass = [[ClassIG alloc] init];
    theNewClass.className = className.text;
    theNewClass.teacherName = teacherName.text;

    NSIndexPath *indexPath;


    theNewClass.subject = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath].textLabel.text;



    // add reminder to array
    NSLog(@"PVC: %@", [classesParentViewController description]);

    [classesParentViewController addNewClass:theNewClass];

}
```

Comment: This type of error is also often associated with memory management problems... if an object has been deallocated, another one (of a different class) might happen to be in the same place in memory.

Answer (score 1):

Declaring, say, a pointer `NSArray* fred` does nothing (other than a sprinkling of compile-time warning messages) to assure that `fred` is an `NSArray`.  It's what you assign to `fred` that counts.  If you assign an `NSDateFormatter`, then that's what `fred` is.

Comment: Yes, but what?  If you get a pointer from a method (that isn't the alloc/init for that class), are you sure you're getting the expected class type?  Especially if you're getting values from a XML or JSON parse, they may not be what you expect.  (The "unrecognized selector" message will tell you what class you really got.)

Comment: Being that I was reading your answer at about 1 AM this morning I didn't understand it fully. I do now, though and it's very helpful! How do I change `nav`'s `topViewController` though?

Comment: UINavigationController topViewController will return whatever controller is "on top".  If it's not one that recognizes `addNewClass` then you get the error.  It's your responsibility to either KNOW what's on top or test what you get back from the call ( `if([classesParentViewController isKindOfClass:[ClassesViewController class]) ...` ) to be sure it's what you want.

Answer (score 1):

Your assumption that the application delegate's navigation controller has a `ClassesViewController` on top is clearly flawed. It has a `HomeViewController` on top. Your structure looks like it may be a little complicated, given that you have a button somewhere wired up to an action in some other part of your controller classes, so there could be a bunch of causative reasons.

First things to check: if you're instantiating buttons programmatically then did you accidentally add the button to the wrong controller? If you're designing everything using the graphical interface designer but keeping it in a single NIB, is it possible you copied and pasted a button and forgot to change what it's wired to?

If you can end up with multiple navigation controllers, are you sure the one held by the application delegate is currently on screen?

Answer (score 0):

the short answer is that typecasting and type conversions are an exercise for the programmer in objc.

read my answer here:

[Passing NSNumber* to NSString* expected-parameter does not cause compiler warning / error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7194003/passing-nsnumber-to-nsstring-expected-parameter-does-not-cause-compiler-warning/7194233#7194233)

...for some more information as to how declaring/casting a variable of an object differs from other languages, and how you can detect those cases.